# How to access Arraylist from inside a Fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, arraylist

Having trouble accessing an arraylist I created in another Fragment class. Essentially I passed an Index through an intent and I know that works because I output that value to the screen for testing purposes. But now I want to use that index number to access the arraylist I created in an Application class.

```
public class item_fragment extends Fragment {



 ArrayList<myItems> myApplication;


 @Override
 public View onCreateView(  LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    myApplication =   ((MyFirstApplication)     getActivity().getApplication()).getItemsArrayList();

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_fragment,container,  false);

      }//ends onCreate View


        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


        EditText item = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
        Intent myIndex = getActivity().getIntent();
        int myValue = myIndex.getIntExtra("Item", 0);



         myItems Item = new myItems();

         Item =  myApplication.get(myValue);

         item.setText(Item.toString());




        }//ends onViewCreated 

}//ends Fragment Class
```

Comment: Keeps saying array size is 0. Not sure why even though I'm accessing the arraylist that I created in another fragment

Comment: First this is not how you pass values from your application to fragments! Please Fragments.setArguments method